# how to make an element stay in place when position changes from absolute to fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this button that on click reveals and expands a div element using a css transition, giving the illusion that the button itself expands. In order to have the div positioned on top of the button i set it to `position: absolute` but when open needs to be `position: fixed`. The problem i have with this is that when it switches between absolute to fixed it moves ruining the expantion effect. Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mari1/wekcx98m/44/) to my example.

```js
function big() {
  document.getElementById("content").classList.add('show');
  document.getElementById("content").classList.add('bigger');
  document.getElementById("content").classList.add('position');
}

function small() {
  document.getElementById("content").classList.remove('bigger');
  document.getElementById("content").classList.remove('position');
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("content").classList.remove("show");
  }, 1000);
  document.getElementById("testo").classList.remove('show');
  document.getElementById("close").classList.remove('show');
}

function delayed() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("testo").classList.add('show');
  }, 1100);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("close").classList.add('show');
  }, 1100);
}
```

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.button>button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vw;
  color: white;
  background-color: pink;
  border: none;
  padding: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button>button:hover {
  background-color: purple;
}

.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  left: 50vw;
  top: 50vw;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, left 1s, top 1s, position 1s;
}

.position {
  position: fixed;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible!important;
}

.bigger {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.close {
  border: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

#testo {
  visibility: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <button onclick="big(); delayed()">expand</button>
  <div id="content" class="fixed hidden">
    <p id="testo">just testing this thing</p>
    <button id="close" class="close" onclick="small()">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's because of `.fixed{ left: 50vw;  top: 50vw; }`. That moves it to the center of the window, in your case. You would need to use a different technique. Here's a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) with some examples. But you probably want to use `const cb =` [element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) along with `cb.top+scrollNode.scrollTop`, and `cb.left+scrollNode.scrollLeft` to get the position, and assign where to expand from.

Comment: Your code is way too verbose. Eg: the function big can be simplified as : `function big() { var content = document.getElementById('content'); content.classList.add('show bigger position'); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set an `opacity` or a `transform: translate()` on the `.button` parent container to make a `fixed` position child relative to the parent vs. the root of the document.

Doing this should give you the effect you're looking for.

```js
function big() {
  document.getElementById("content").classList.add('show');
  document.getElementById("content").classList.add('bigger');
  document.getElementById("content").classList.add('position');
}

function small() {
  document.getElementById("content").classList.remove('bigger');
  document.getElementById("content").classList.remove('position');
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.getElementById("content").classList.remove("show");
  }, 1000);
  document.getElementById("testo").classList.remove('show');
  document.getElementById("close").classList.remove('show');
}

function delayed() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("testo").classList.add('show');
  }, 1100);
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("close").classList.add('show');
  }, 1100);
}
```

```css
html,body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.button {
  position: relative;
  /* opacity: 1; */
  transform: translate(0, 0);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.button > button {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  color: white;
  background-color: pink;
  border: none;
  padding: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button > button:hover {
  background-color: purple;
}

.fixed {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: pink;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 75px;
  transition: width 1s, height 1s, left 1s, top 1s, position 1s;
}

.position {
  position: fixed;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.show {
  visibility: visible !important;
}

.bigger {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.close {
  border: none;
  visibility: hidden;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.close:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: black;
}

#testo {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="button">
  <button onclick="big(); delayed()">expand</button>
  <div id="content" class="fixed hidden">
    <p id="testo">just testing this thing</p>
    <button id="close" class="close" onclick="small()">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can place fixed position to content after your animation is done
so your animation effect wont ruin . i have edited your fiddle see if this works as you like
[edited fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amirrahman132132/ytkaLmsg/2/)

```
function big() {
  document.getElementById("content").classList.add('show');
  document.getElementById("content").classList.add('bigger');
  setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("content").classList.add('position');  
  },1000)

}

function small() {
  document.getElementById("content").classList.remove('bigger');
  document.getElementById("content").classList.remove('position');
  setTimeout(()=>{
    document.getElementById("content").classList.remove("show");
  }, 1000);
  document.getElementById("testo").classList.remove('show');
  document.getElementById("close").classList.remove('show');
}

function delayed() {
  setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("testo").classList.add('show');},1100);
  setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("close").classList.add('show');},1100);
}
```