# The same horizontal position for "fixed" and "absolute" position elements

Tags: css

I'm trying display a "fixed" element at the same position as "absolute" element relative to it's parent:

```css
.content
{
  position: relative;
  max-width: 20em;
  margin: 2em 5em;
  resize:both;
  height: 200vh;

}

.menu
{
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: pink;
  top: -1.5em;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* change to fixed position when focused */
.menu:focus
{
  cursor: not-allowed;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0.5em;
}

.menu::after
{
  content: "absolute (click me)";
}
.menu:focus::after
{
  content: "fixed (click anywhere else)";
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  some long text that might wrap or not
  <div class="menu" tabindex="0">
    Position:
  </div>
</div>
```

It works perfectly with `position: absolute`, but `position: fixed` moves the element outside of the parent container boundaries.
Is there a way maybe "calculate" position for fixed element so it would remain at the same horizontal position when no static widths are set?

*Whoever is pushing this as [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216638/how-to-make-an-element-stay-in-place-when-position-changes-from-absolute-to-fixe), the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69217126/2930038) in the other topic does not solve the issue, it uses `transform: translate()` which makes `fixed` element scroll instead of stay in one place!*

Comment: @disinfor I'm looking for pure CSS solution

Comment: It is a pure CSS solution. The JS is incidental. The very first sentence of my answer is what you're looking for. Adding `transform: translate(0,0)` to the parent `.content` will make a `fixed` child position against that parent, rather than the the window.

Comment: Unfraternally the `fixed` element become `absolute` in this case, it scrolls with the parent.

Comment: _which makes fixed element scroll instead of stay in one place!_ this was important information to answer your question. Glad someone provided you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand that `position: fixed` will be tied to the window. So in order to place the block in that point, you need to know the dimensions, the margin, and even the width of the scrollbar. So to answer your question, you could do something like this:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  --scrollbar-width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: var(--scrollbar-width);
}

.content {
  --max-width: 20em;
  --margin-y: 2em;
  --margin-x: 2em;
  position: relative;
  max-width: var(--max-width);
  margin: var(--margin-y) var(--margin-x);
  resize: both;
  height: 200vh;
  padding-top: var(--margin-y);
}

.menu {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: pink;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* change to fixed position when focused */
.menu:focus {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  position: fixed;
  top: var(--margin-y);
  right: calc(100vw - var(--max-width) -  var(--margin-x) - var(--scrollbar-width));
}

@media (width < 20em) {
  .menu:focus {
    right: var(--margin-x);
  }
}

.menu::after {
  content: 'absolute (click me)';
}
.menu:focus::after {
  content:  'fixed (click anywhere else)';
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  some long text that might wrap or not
  <div class="menu" tabindex="0">
    Position:
  </div>
</div>
```

Or use `position: sticky;` if you know `.menu` height:

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}

.content{
  --max-width: 20em;
  --margin-y: 2em;
  --margin-x: 2em;
  position: relative;
  max-width: var(--max-width);
  margin: var(--margin-y) var(--margin-x);
  padding-top: var(--margin-y);
  resize: both;
  height: 200vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.menu {
  --border-width: 1px;
  --height: 1lh;
  border: var(--border-width) solid red;
  background-color: pink;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.menu:focus {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  position: sticky;
  margin-top: calc(-1 * var(--margin-y));
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--margin-y) - var(--height) - 2 * var(--border-width));
}

.menu::after {
  content: 'absolute (click me)';
}

.menu:focus::after {
  content: 'fixed (click anywhere else)';
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="menu" tabindex="0">
    Position:
  </div>
  some long text that might wrap or not
</div>
```